# Creating Floating Action Button in Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, fragment, floating-action-button

I just wanted to build a floating action bar in one of the fragments but unfortunately, when I run the app it crashes.

```js
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        add_button =(FloatingActionButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        add_giftcard =(FloatingActionButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.add_giftcard);
        add_flight =(FloatingActionButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.add_flight);

        //animations
        fabOpen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( getActivity(), R.anim.fab_open);
        fabClose = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( getActivity(), R.anim.fab_close);

        rotateForward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( getActivity(), R.anim.rotate_forward);
        rotateBackward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( getActivity(), R.anim.rotate_backward);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to the fragment lifecycle, the view should be initialized within the onCreateView() callback. Use the below snippet.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_view, container, false);

add_button =(FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        add_giftcard =(FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.add_giftcard);
        add_flight =(FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.add_flight);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Stelian Claudiu, does the above solution work for you, if not pls update the complete fragment code.